# Windows phone 8.1 contact store changes

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

i am working on an application where i need to get the changes made to the contact store on the phone.

there exists method for this in the ContactStore class, it is the GetChangesAsync() method.

There seem to exist no samples for this. Anyone has any idea how to get the changes made to the contact store ?